# how to pass parameters to batch file using java textbox

Tags: java, batch-file

I am running a batch file, where I want to pass parameters from Textbox

Batch: test.bat

```
@echo off  
set par1=%1  
echo Parameter 1 is %par1%  
mkdir %par1%
```

Java:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\test.bat");
```

How to pass parameter to `Test.bat` file?

Comment: And since you seem to be a newbie to using a `Process`..  Please read, and implement the suggestions of, [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the parameter to the command line:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\test.bat xyz");
```

This will pass `xyz` to the batch file.

But `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` is not a good way to execute an external program. You should use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: Please link to the latest JavaDocs available.  For tips on getting the relevant link, see Point 2 of this [RFE](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  Otherwise +1 - I've deleted my (very speculative) answer.

Comment: @Andrew thanks. I think there is someway to make google search to show the results from Java 7 (or whatever) at the top but I am not able to figure it out. In this case, I just got lazy and did not change it by hand.

Comment: @Andrew there are no links at the [rfe](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875). All the url like strings start with "download. customer .com" (note spaces). And the ["link to latest API"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) it mentions result in 404. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for being dumb. Voted :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass them in an array:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"c:\\test.bat", "-p", "firstParam", "--secondparam"} )
```

Comment: -p stands for parameter?